# How to get raw place rating from Google Places API?

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to get place rating from Google Places and I stuck on this part of code:

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  service.getDetails({
      placeId: "ChIJ2fNZsMQ0GkcRCt39huGpijo"
    },
    function(place, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var rating = place.rating;
        $('.google_rating').html(rating);
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="rating" id="google_rating">
  <div class="google_rating"></div><span class="rating_star">&#9733;</span>
</div>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1awNWLs_8JOTHWaC08TCUOo0r0PxPqvY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

I don't need any map, just raw rating of specific place (place ID). What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PlacesService` constructor takes either a `google.maps.Map` object or an HTMLDivElement:

> ### PlacesService(attrContainer)
>
> **Parameters:**
>  
>   attrContainer:  HTMLDivElement|Map
>   Creates a new instance of the PlacesService that renders attributions in the specified container.

Don't construct it with a map if you don't need one, use an HTMLDivElement like this:

```
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("placeAttr"));
```

[image: screenshot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(document.getElementById("placeAttr"));

  service.getDetails({
      placeId: "ChIJ2fNZsMQ0GkcRCt39huGpijo"
    },
    function(place, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var rating = place.rating;
        $('.google_rating').html(rating);
      }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rating" id="google_rating">
  <div class="google_rating"></div><span class="rating_star">&#9733;</span>
</div>
<div id="placeAttr"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB1awNWLs_8JOTHWaC08TCUOo0r0PxPqvY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```